# Size of Form is messed up after disabling control box with Custom Location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I did some research and could not find anyone even mentioning the problem I'm having, if I set up a form in c# and compile the application it looks and works perfectly fine, but when I disable the control box the size of the form seems to shift and everything is messed up, but ONLY while the program is running, it looks perfectly find and normal in the gui builder.

I've had the issue for a while and I usually get around it by making the form bigger and testing until it looks right, but it's somewhat annoying and I was hoping maybe someone else has a better solution?

**EDIT:** I moved some things around and anchored the EXIT button to all 4 sides to better show the difference in outputs between the two settings

**EDIT2:** I have found that this ONLY happens when using a custom location (IE location != 0, 0)

**EDIT3:** In my project it gets SMALLER and the formborderstyle workaround doesnt work as it did in my test project

VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L5v2y5YCHio&feature=youtu.be

I also found that setting FormBorderStyle=Fixed is a possible work around for now, I have opened a bug report on visual studio's site to see if we can get this fixed!

I'll update if anything new comes up

**WITH control box:**

[image]

**WITHOUT control box:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show some code ? How are you disabling the control  ? etc..

Comment: Just changing the check box in the properties view to False for "ControlBox" not really any code involved

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in visual studio that relates to custom form locations and the control box, generally setting the formbordersize = fixedsingle will solve this, however in my case I was changing the location in code during form initialization:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.Location = new Point(w.Location.X + (w.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2), w.Location.Y);
```

By changing the code around (reversing) as so:

```
this.Location = new Point(w.Location.X + (w.Width / 2) - (this.Width / 2), w.Location.Y);
InitializeComponent();
```

This issue was resolved, I don't know exactly what causes this, nor why it is fixed, technically the initialize component has a location set in it that should override my location, but it works for me.

I will not accept this as an answer, someone that can explain it better, in more detail, why or how it works, I will accept THAT answer.

Thank you for your time!